# Which Wildfly version to use with Windows10 and Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, wildfly

I'm a beginner at Java EE. Please advise me which is the good Wildfly verson for Eclipse Mars and Windows10? Thanks for help

Comment: I would not think that there are good or bad versions; best use the current release.

Comment: Thank you! I'm attending a Java EE course. There Eclipse Mars and Wildfly 8.2.1 Final on Windows 7. I installed the same at home on Windows 10. All web projects that work at the course say error 404 at home. My first tip was that Wildfly 8.2.1 Final and Windows10 cannot work together.

Comment: WildFly 8.x works just fine on Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you very much! So something else causes my error 404 :(

Comment: You might try to ask a new question. But maybe you just have to change the URL/path a if you have another configuration at home. And check if the server starts and the application is deployed successfully

Answer (score 0):

Hi follow the simple steps below, there is no problem at all with any version on windows, 8 works well, 9 or even 10.

1. Make sure you have java properly installed on your machine, for example if you open a Command prompt and press 'java -version' you get something back.
2. Download the latest version of wildfly from [here](http://wildfly.org/downloads/) as a zip.
3. Unzip the file and you have the app server folder. Go to the /bin folder and try to start the app server using the /bin/standalone.bat (does it start? is it booting?). If yes stop it by pressing Ctrl +C.
4. Once you make sure the above steps work, then you can go to your eclipse and add the Application server, installation, to your list of servers for example see [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/configuring-eclipse-to-use-wildfly-8) for specific details .

To cut a long story short, wildfly is the easiest app server to install, it is just a zip, you unzip it and if you have setup java properly on your machine it justs runs - no installers not a big deal actually :)

Hope that helps.